# Why is the risk equal to the empirical risk when taking the expectation over the samples?

Tags: notation, definition, machine-learning

From Understanding Machine Learning: From theory to algorithms:

> Let $S$ be a set of $m$ samples from a set $Z$ and $w^*$ be an arbitrary vector.  Then $\Bbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[L_S(w^*)] = L_D(w^*)$.
>
> Where: $L_S(w^*) \equiv \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^ml(w^*, z_i)$ and $z_i \in S$, $L_D(w^*) \equiv \Bbb E_{z \text{ ~ }D}[l(w^*, z)]$, $D$ is a distribution on $Z$, and $l(\text{_},\text{_} )$ is a loss function.

I see that $$\Bbb E_S[L_S(w^*)] = \Bbb E_S[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^ml(w^*, z_i)] = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Bbb E_S[l(w^*, z_i)]$$ and
$$L_D(w^*) = \Bbb E_z[l(w^*, z)] = \sum_{z \in Z} l(w^*, z)D(z)$$

But how are these two equal?  $\Bbb E_S$ is an expectation  over samples $S$ of size $m$ whereas $\Bbb E_z$ is an expectation over all samples in $Z$.

Comment: In your first formula all the terms inside the sum are equal because each time you draw $z_i$ from the same distribution. You  have $m$ equal terms each equal to the true risk and the $m$ 's cancel out.

Comment: Actually your sum should contain the expected value over $z_i$ from $D$ which is the distribution on your instance space $X$

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I don't understand what you mean by "the sum should contain the expected value...".

Comment: And why are all the terms inside the sum equal?  That means the loss function is constant regardless of what value you substitute in.

Comment: The loss function itself depends on the point, but its expected value over points drawn from $D$ (that is, the true error) only depends on your hypothesis $w^*$.

Comment: I'm not sure how that shows the two equations are equal.  Can you elaborate more?  I don't see how the notations between the two equations show the equality.

Answer (score 0):

The sample is IID - taking the expectation with respect to the sample is equivalent to taking the expectation with respect to each data point and this expectations are all equal ("same distribution").

$$\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Bbb E_S[l(w^*, z_{i})] = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Bbb E_{z_{i}}[l(w^*, z_{i})] =  \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Bbb E_{z}[l(w^*, z_)] =\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \ L_{D}(w*)  = L_{D}(w*) $$

First two sums are equal because each term depends only on one RV - $z_{i}$  (is a constant with respect to other RV ) and the expectation of a constant is just the constant .

Comment: How is $\large \Bbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[l(w^*, z_i)] = \Bbb E_{z \text{ ~ } D}[l(w^*, z_i)]$?  By their definitions:

$\large \Bbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[l(w^*, z_i)] = \sum_{S \space \text{size $m \subseteq$  Z}}l(w^*, z_i)D^m(S)$ and 

$\large \Bbb E_{z \text{ ~ } D}[l(w^*, z_i)] = \sum_{z \in Z} l(w^*, z_i) D(z)$.

How is 

 $\large \sum_{S \space \text{size $m \subseteq$  Z}}l(w^*, z_i)D^m(S)=\sum_{z \in Z} l(w^*, z_i) D(z)$?

Comment: By expanding the notation you get $$\Bbb E_S[L_S(w^*)] = \Bbb E_S[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^ml(w^*, z_i)] = \frac{1}{m}(l(w^*, z_{S_1}) + \dots + l(w^*, z_{S_n}) + l(w^*, z_{S^{'}_1}) + \dots + l(w^*, z_{S^{'}_1}) + \dots)D^m(S)$$ $$=$$ $$(D(z))^m \frac{1}{m} (  l(w^*, z_{S_1}) + \dots + l(w^*, z_{S_n}) + l(w^*, z_{S^{'}_1}) + \dots + l(w^*, z_{S^{'}_1}) + \dots )$$ and this seems to overcount each element as they can appear multiple times in each subset.

Comment: The idea is that taking the expectation with respect to S is like taking the expectation with respect to each $z_{i}$, one by one . And since all $z_{i}$ follow the same distribution the expectations are equal . There are m equal terms devided by m .

Comment: You said there's $m$ equal terms divided by $m$, what terms are equal in the equation I gave above?

Comment: The equation in your comment is not correct (or I don't understand your notation) .It does not make much sens to have a probability distribution as a factor.

Comment: I will clarify the notation.  The probability distribution is a necessary factor by the definition of an expected value.  $\Bbb E_{z \text{ ~ } D}[h] \equiv \sum_{z \in Z} h D(z)$ where $D(z) \equiv \text{Prob}(Z=z)$.  In the same way, $\Bbb E_{S \text{ ~ } D^m}[h] \equiv \sum_{S \in Z^m}[h] D^m(S) $ where $D^m(S)$ is $\text{Prob}(Z=z_1, Z=z_2, \dots, Z = z_m)$ and since it's i.i.d. we have $D^m(S) = D(z_1) \times D(z_2) \times \dots \times D(z_n) = [D(z)]^m$.  Given these definitions, is my equation correct?  Or if not, what mistake am I making and what should be the correct notation?

Comment: It's almost correct, but you also need to integrate over the values of z (think about the definition of the expectation) . But this details are not needed , the relation follws easily from the properties of the expectation .

Comment: Let $z_i=S_i$, where $S_i$ means the $i$th element of of $S$. And let $S', S'', \dots$ be other elements of $Z^m$.Then:$$\large \Bbb E_S[L_S(w^*)] = \Bbb E_S[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^ml(w^*,S_i)]$$ $$=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Bbb E_S[l(w^*, S_i)] = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Biggl(\sum_{S \in Z^m}[l(w^*, S_i)]D^m(S) \Biggr)$$ $$=\frac{[D(z)]^m}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Biggl( l(w^*,S_i) + l(w^*,S'_i) +l(w^*,S''_i)+\dots \Biggr)$$  $$=\frac{[D(z)]^m}{m} \Biggl( \biggl( l(w^*, S_1) + l(w^*,S'_1)+\dots \biggr) + \biggl(l(w^*, S_2) + l(w^*, S_2') + \dots \biggr)  + \dots+\biggl(\text{$m$-th sum}\biggr)\Biggr)$$

Comment: and

$$L_D(w^*) = \Bbb E_z[l(w^*, z)] = \sum_{z \in Z} l(w^*, z)D(z)$$

So these two equations are claimed to be equal.  What $m$ elements are repeated in the fully expanded first equation?

Comment: In your comment the definition of the expectation is not correct , $$E_{S}[l(w^{8},S_{i})] = \int_{S}l(w^{8},S_{i})D^{m}(S)$$

Comment: For a finite/countable domain, the expectation is defined as $\sum_{z \in Z} l(z) D(z)$ while for a continuous domain the expectation is defined as $\int_{z}zD(z)dz$.  If you're saying it only works for the continuous case, why doesn't it work for the countable case?  And can you show how the equations are equal for the continuous case?

Comment: Edit:  Continuous is defined as $\int_z l(z) D(z) dz$.

Comment: It's not important if the RV is continuous or discret (for this particular problem) . The only important thing is that if the RVs came from the same distribution , they have the same expectation . .This is way all terms are equal .